# custom mini router in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, router

I've to implement a custom mini router and have been looking at express js for inspirations.

Can anyone guide me on express js creates route handlers under the hood.

For instance, how the following can be implemented?

Node server code

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) { //how routing is done after?
    //req???
    req.get("/customers", function(){}) 
    req.get("/customers/:id", function(){})
}).listen(9615);
```

is express js using regular expressions? Please also point to the right script in the github repository.

Comment: Express uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) to convert paths to regular expressions.

Comment: thanks @robertklep, it's great, that's very close, I don't now regular expressions too much but can you write me an example as an answer to handle above two routes using regular expressions.

Comment: @robertklep I found the regex as well from their github page, please check http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

Comment: An even simpler solution could be [`paramify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paramify).

Comment: I'm very happy to crack this using my own code with just the regular expressions I got, I tend to write low level code without dependencies around very specific and narrow set of requirements, if you will, you can write your answer while merging `http.createServer` code and my answer and that will solve my problem.

Comment: @robertklep I'll come up with an implementation and will ping you perhaps if I've a question, objective is to match working of express js with minimalistic low level approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep).

Under the hood express js uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp).

I also found the regular expression from their page that is used by express js to parse the URL [link](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/)

```
/^(?:\/(?=$))?$/i
```

There's not much re-inventing the wheel involved in here when all I wanted is a basic router without getting the whole framework and all of it's dependencies in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check this https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js. This is a separate module of expressjs for routing and you can pluck it out for your personal use without reinventing the wheel all over.

[EDIT] - To give idea how it might be done.

```
var routes = [];
var app = {};
app.get = function(pattern, cb) {
    var splits = pattern.split("/");
    var route = "";
    var regex = "";
    for(i=0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        if (splits[i].indexOf(':') === -1) {
            route += splits[i]+"/";
        } else {
            regex = splits[i].replace(":", "");
        }
    }
    routes.push({ route : routes, regex : regex, cb: cb });
}

app.get("/customers", callback);

.
.
.
// handle incoming request. requestPath comes from server
var requestPath = "/customers"; // example only.

app.handleRequest(requestPath) {
    for(i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        if(routes[i].route === requestPath) {
             cb = routes[i].cb;
        }
    }
    cb();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I've to reinvent the wheel and really understand what's going on under the hood, looking for a code solution to my question

Comment: But why? IMHO, simply use the function present in index.js which routes the express framework. A basic router is not difficult but then adding features would be a pain.

Comment: true, that's why I'm looking for very basic implementation using my routes, how have they done it?

Comment: thanks, can you please merge your example with my `http.createServer` code

Comment: @robertklep pointed me to a direction, see the regex http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/ Express uses path-to-regexp

Comment: Will do it later so that I can pass relevant params etc. Will make  a github repo for it. Btw by that time, check this https://github.com/kieran/barista . checkout the lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [the Express JS documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). It would be pretty much it. For example, a piece of code using Express JS:

```
// GET method route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('GET request to the homepage');
});

// POST method route
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('POST request to the homepage');
});
```

As for regular expressions, yes, you can use them. For example:

```
app.get('/ab(cd)?e', function(req, res) {
    res.send('ab(cd)?e');
});
```

Besides that, please take look at one example in [the Express JS GitHub repository](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation).

As for the Router implementation in Express JS, look at [their GitHub code (router script)](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js).

Comment: no I mean how to write a source code of a router, not to implement express js router

Comment: In the end of the answer I put a link to the Express JS router implementation for your inspiration if you really have to code your own solution.

Comment: i can't really understand from their github repo, if you can please tell me how they have done using my two routers